# Animations in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using `RotateAnimation` and `TranslateAnimation` in my game project. After completing rotate i'm saving  image next using TranslateAnimation. It works fine, but completing rotateanimation the image blinks once.

```
public void Trainplace(int x,int y,Bitmap b){
     param.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
     Train.setLayoutParams(param);
     Train.setImageBitmap(b);
    Train.setVisibility(0);
}
public void Trainmove(int x){
    TAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,x);
    TAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    TAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    TAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    //TAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
    Train.startAnimation(TAnimation);
}
public void Trainrotate(int a,int b,int c,int d){

    RAnimation=new RotateAnimation(a,b,c,d);
    RAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    RAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    RAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    Train.startAnimation(RAnimation);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.b:


        Trainplace(20, 255,bmpy1);
        Trainrotate(0,90,50,25);

        //Stop button clicks
        //B.setEnabled(false);

        break;


    case R.id.b2:
        Trainplace(35, 230,bmpx1);
        Trainrotate(0,-90,20,-30);

        RAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {


            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

            }


            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

                int p=0;
                while(p<=1){
                if(RAnimation.hasEnded()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                p=2;
                }
                }


                Trainplace(85, 170,bmpy1);

                Trainmove(-100);
            }
        });


        break;
```

My problem is with completing the rotateanimation - the current image is replaced by another image (ex. my train image rotated 90 degrees then i m placed 90 degrees rotated image in that place )and then move forward by using Translateanimation this is working.

When placing the image inbetween, after completing Rotateanimation and before starting Translateanimation the train image is blinking once.

The same image will place with noproblem (means Translateanimation to Rotateanimation).

Answer (score 0):

When I get blinks in animation, its most probably because the animation listeners 'onAnimationEnd' is firing before the animation is actually done.

You can create av custom view or layout and overide its 'animationEnd' method and add a interface so you can set up a listener.

Here's an example

CustomLayout class

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private LayoutAnimationListener mListner;

    public CustomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAnimationEnd() {
        super.onAnimationEnd();
        if(mListner != null){
            mListner.onAnimationEnd(CustomLayout.this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAnimationStart() {
        super.onAnimationStart();
        if(mListner != null){
            mListner.onAnimationStart(CustomLayout.this);
        }
    }

    public static interface LayoutAnimationListener {
        //Notifies the start of the animation.
        void onAnimationStart(CustomLayout cLayout);
        //Notifies the end of the animation.
        void onAnimationEnd(CustomLayout cLayout);
    }

    public void setLayoutAnimationListener(LayoutAnimationListener listener){
        mListner = listener;
    }
}
```

So in your activity you can use it as a normal linearlayout and instead of adding a animation listener to the animation, you can add it to the layout like

```
    com.blessan.CustomLayout layout   = 
            (com.blessan.CustomLayout)findViewById(R.id.counts_layout);
    LayoutAnimationListener layoutAnimListener = new LayoutAnimationListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(CustomLayout cLayout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(CustomLayout cLayout) {

        }

    };
    layout.setLayoutAnimationListener(layoutAnimListener);
```

This might work for you. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for ur responce, my problem is copleting the rotateanimation the current image replaced by another image(ex. my train image rotated 90 degrees then i m placed 90 degrees rotated image in that place )and then move forward by using Translateanimation ok it is working. my problem is placing the image inbtween after completin Rotateanimation and before starting Translateanimation the train image is blink once.same image will place noproblem(means Translateanimation to Rotateanimation). please give me answer..........